# git-receive-pack: command not found

Tags: git, ssh

I'm trying to use Git to `push` to my remote server, but it keeps saying

> git-receive-pack: command not found.

I tried searching and some people say it's the server, others say it's the client.

OS: Windows 8 64bit 
Server: Cent OS with `CPanel` the newest version

Git is built in to `CPanel`, I didn't install it.

[image: Screenshot]

Maybe if I knew which system was saying the error I could troubleshoot it better. Also, I know nothing about `SSH`. I tried inserting the SSH key that was generated by `GIT` but when I tried using `SSH://` it would still just ask for the password. So something might not be setup correctly. I added the git user to the system with the repository like the git instructions said to do, but I added a password to the user just to see if it would let me login without SSH.

Answer (score 15):

When you run *git push* the `send-pack` part of the protocol is running on your, local  side, and it connects to the `receive-pack` part running on the remote side.

So let's say you run *git push*, where your remote *origin* repo is configured to use ssh and is mapped to *server.com*. Git uses `send-pack` to initiate a connection over ssh to the server extracted from the remote URL <sup>*</sup>:

```
$ ssh server.com "git-receive-pack /path/to/repo.git"
```

<sub><sup>*</sup> When the repository was previously cloned or added as `git remote add origin ssh://server.com/path/to/repo.git`</sub>

Note that the quoted command is run by ssh on the remote server, and it is possible that `git-receive-pack` could not be located there. You can test for this yourself as follows:

```
$ ssh server.com "type -p git-receive-pack" || echo "git-receive-pack not found"
```

If indeed the `git-receive-pack` command could not be located on the remote - for instance, because it is not in the `PATH` of your remote login shell, you can tell *git push* where it should look for it by running:

```
$ git push --receive-pack=/server/com/full/path/to/git-receive-pack
```

And you can save typing that every time you push by telling git to remember to use the explicit path via the config:

```
$ git config remote.origin.receivepack /server/explicit/path/to/git-receive-pack
```

Comment: Does that mean that git is trying to send it to my local PC? My server knows what the git-receive-pack command means, but my local PC doesn't because it's just the client.

Comment: @user3396392 You local PC, where you work with git, should have all the relevant git binaries (such as `git` itselft, `git-send-pack` etc) in its PATH. On the remote server you should care only whether it knows about `git-receive-pack`.

Answer (score 2):

The real answer is that even though I put

> alias git-receive-pack="/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/git-receive-pack"

I still need to add it to my `~/.bashrc`

> export PATH=$PATH:"/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin"

Also, on a side note the whole `stdin: is not a TTY` error can be fixed by removing the `/home/git/.bashrc` file.

As stated in: http://webhostingneeds.com/Git_stdin_is_not_a_tty

Comment: Aliasing  `git` as `git-receive-pack` is wrong, don't do it, it masks the problem at best.

Comment: great,, it was worked for me..

one thing, for stdin issue :
my server do not have git directory on /home.

so what should i do for fix them?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked all the answers and tried all. But in my case I because of comedian for myself.

Do you know why?

**Because Git wasn't installed on server**

After I have installed git into my centos server, it's good.

```
yum install git -y
```

No reboot, nothing we have to do. I have pulled, and pushed.
Without git installed on the server, this error may have been shown, it's my case, and others have other cases. Cheers :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use git push options to set the full path of git-receive-pack.

There is a sample working on my CoreELEC device:

```
git push -u origin master --exec /opt/bin/git-receive-pack
```