# git-receive-pack: command not found. Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, ubuntu-14.04, githooks, digital-ocean

PS - I am already through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22271560/git-receive-pack-command-not-found)

I am trying to do a quick auto deployment using git by following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps).

Everything seems to be fine. Whenever I do a push, i receive this error:

```
bash: git-receive-pack: command not found
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

But on the remote machine the below command works just fine:

```
git-receive-pack
```

I don't know where the issue is. Any help?

Comment: So even a `git config remote.origin.receivepack /server/explicit/path/to/git-receive-pack` does not work?

Comment: Did you use the same path as the one you see on the server when typing `which git-receive-pack`?